# "Учись склонениям" или "учись склонению"?

Tags: орфография, единственное-множественное-число, окончания

Как правильно: "учись склонен**ию** слов" или "учись склонени**ям** слов"?

Answer (score 1):

Словарь-справочник лингвистических терминов (Д. Э. Розенталь, М. А. Теленкова):
[склонение](http://endic.ru/linguistics/Sklonenie-467.html)
**1.** Изменение существительных по падежам (для большинства имен и по числам), а для прилагательных и других согласуемых слов также по родам.
**2.** Парадигма словоизменения склоняемых слов. *Первое, второе и третье склонения имен существительных. Типы склонения имен прилагательных.*

Подавляющее большинство склоняемых слов в русском языке имеет один вариант склонения. Поэтому если говорится об отдельных словах (п. 1), то я бы выбрала единственное число: **учись склонению слов**.
Более подходящие варианты: *учи склонение слов, учись склонять слова.*

> Отец отдал Микеланджело в школу Франческо да Урбино во Флоренции, и мальчик должен был **учиться склонять и спрягать латинские слова** у этого первого составителя латинской грамматики (С. М. Брилиант. Микеланджело Буонарроти. Его жизнь и художественная деятельность).

Если же речь идет о группах слов, относящихся к разным склонениям (п. 2), то можно сказать так: **учи склонения.**

[Учим склонения и падежи: для начальной школы](https://books.google.ee/books?id=lb2EAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=%22%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&source=bl&ots=B6NwtaN-jl&sig=ACfU3U2w2wXFm_KUhoe4amZrLrv432FI-w&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_1riKw6rwAhXks4sKHc5jD8AQ6AEwBHoECBsQAw#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&f=false)